# Can we always find a stochastic process whose autocorrelation function is a given positive semidefinite function?

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification, stochastic-processes, signal-processing

The auto-correlation function of a stochastic process is defined by $$R(t_1, t_2)=\mathbb{E}[X(t_1)X(t_2)]$$

We say that a function is positive semidefinite if and only if

$$\forall x,y: f(x,y)^2 \leq f(x,x)f(y,y)$$

It is easy to see that if $X(t)$ is a stochastic process, then using the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality we have

$$R(t_1, t_2)^2=\mathbb{E}[X(t_1)X(t_2)]^2 \leq \mathbb{E}[X(t_1)^2]\mathbb{E}[X(t_2)^2]=R(t_1, t_1)R(t_2, t_2)$$

So, I wonder if one is given a positive semidefinite function $f$, is it always possible to find a stochastic process whose auto-correlation function is $f$?

Note: I'm looking for answers that do not use measure theory.

Comment: By Kolmogorov's consistency theorem, yes.

Comment: Yes, they are referring to the same theorem. The Wikipedia page is talking about continuous time processes. You should read it a bit more carefully. I can write more later if no one else responds.

Comment: @Calculon Oops, you're right. Is it possible to do this without measure theory? The question has been brought up as a bonus question in an undergrad course. And we're allowed to research it on the internet. But I think we're not allowed to use measure theory as it is out of the scope of the course.

Comment: How do you define a stochastic process without using measure theory?

Comment: @MikeHawk  A family of random variables parametrized by time. It's not 100% rigorous, but it convinces engineers. Doesn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously not. Consider $R(x,y)=-1$. But I'll assume you also meant to require that $R(x,x)\ge 0$. However, even this is not sufficient.

To see this, pick any 3 time points $t_1, t_2, t_3$ and consider the random variables $X_{t_1}, X_{t_2}, X_{t_3}$. Define the matrix $A_{ij}=E(X_{t_i}X_{t_j})=R(t_i, t_j)$. I claim $A$ must be non-negative definite. Indeed, for any vector $v$, $(v,Av)=\sum_{i,j}v_iv_jA_{ij}=\sum_{i,j}v_iv_jE(X_{t_i}X_{t_j})=E\sum_{i,j}(v_iX_{t_i})(v_jX_{t_j})=E(\sum_i v_iX_{t_i})^2\ge 0$. By the same argument, it must be the case that $\sum_{i,j=1}^Nv_iv_jR(t_i,t_j)\ge 0$ for any $N$, $v_i$ and time points $t_i$. A function which satisfies this condition is called a Mercer kernel.

To see that your condition of positive-semidefiniteness does not imply being a Mercer kernel, it is sufficient to exhibit a symmetric matrix M such that:
1. the diagonal entries of M are positive
2. all 2x2 minors have non-negative determinant, and 
3. M has a negative eigenvalue. I leave it as an exercise to construct such a matrix.

Interestingly, if R is a Mercer kernel, then the answer to your question is yes, and the process can be described somewhat explicitly. I'll assume that t is restricted to lie in the unit interval $[0,1]$. By Mercer's theorem, we can write $R(x,y)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \lambda_i f_i(x)f_i(y)$, where the functions satisfy $\int_0^1 R(x,y)f_i(y)=\lambda_if_i(x)$.

Now let $X_t=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \sqrt{\lambda_i}\xi_if_i(t)$ where $\xi_i$ are iid normal random variables with mean $0$ and standard deviation $1$. The series converges almost surely by Kolmogorov's Two SEries theorem.

We see that $EX_tX_s=\sum_{i,j}\sqrt{\lambda_i\lambda_j}f_i(t)f_j(s)E(\xi_i\xi_j)$. By independence, we have $E(\xi_i\xi_j)=E\xi_iE\xi_j=\delta_{ij}$. So $EX_tX_s=\sum_i\lambda_if_i(t)f_i(s)=R(t,s)$ as desired.

Comment: because $E(X_{t}^2)=R(t,t)$ cannot be negative